# How to move JavaScript events from HTML properly? (Do you know other ways?)

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I started to make an really simple experiment, just to learn the basics of JavaScript. The problem is that I'm trying to move the events (like: `onmouseover`, `onclick`) from the HTML code to the external js file, that already contain the functions. I've tried few methods but nothing works.

I believe that must be something really simple, but I can't figure it out now.
If you can and want to help, please take a look: http://www.animatedbuilding.net16.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign event handlers programmatically, like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('your_click_target');
elem.addEventListener('click', your_click_handler);
```

More info [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Comment: @Erick: `elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { toggleopacity("luz")});`